# How do I define an alias for a register in gnu assembler?

Tags: assembly, gnu-assembler, superh

I have test.s with the following line:

```
mov #1, r0
```

This assembles with no issues.

From the gnu assembler manual, I should be able to do:

```
.equ foo, r0
```

or

```
.set foo, r0
```

and then do:

```
mov #1, foo
```

but this gives me the error: `invalid operands for opcode`

What am I doing wrong? How do I create an alias for a register?

Arch is SuperH.

Comment: `.set` and `.equ` define symbols as numbers or other symbol addresses, not text-substitutions.  IDK if GAS's macro processor can do that for single tokens; it's often used with a separate preprocessor like M4 or CPP. 
 If you name your source files `.S` instead of `.s`, `gcc -c foo.S` will run it through CPP first, so stuff like `#include` and `#define foo r0` work.